# jQuery Selector for checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to loop on the checked checkbox:

```
$("input:checked").each(function () {
    //SOME CODE
});
```

But I only want to loop on checkbox which has an ID=chkCom. What should be my correct selector? Thanks!

Comment: are there multiple element with the id `chkCom`

Comment: `$("#chkCom:checked")`

Comment: Tell us a bit more--what do you intend to put in the `each()` method?

Comment: Did you get your answer? Can you tell us more about what should happen within the `each()` method?

Answer (score 1):

You would use:

```
$("#chkCom:checked").each(function () {
    // ... 
});
```

Since it looks like you are trying to iterate over multiple elements with an `id` of `#chkCom`, this implies there there are duplicate `id`s. It's worth mentioning that [`id`s *must* be unique](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20/tests/test185.html), use a class instead.

Comment: Why "in this instance"? It's a checkbox, not a radio set, so nothing to imply that there would be an element with the same `name`, much less `id`.

Comment: @JeromyFrench The OP is using an `.each()` loop. If they are trying to iterate over elements with an `id` of `chkCom`, that implies that there are duplicate `id`s. If there aren't duplicate `id`s, then there is no need for an `.each()` loop.

Comment: A fair point. Perhaps OP isn't aware that he doesn't need the `each()` method (came across *that*..."phenomenon" while doing a code review this past Thursday).

Comment: @JeromyFrench Yep. That's certainly a possibility too, haha.